# Include Activities Search on GNOME to include files

Tags: gnome, search

I am currently running Pop_OS 21 but with the cosmic desktop disabled, so using generic GNOME desktop. When pressing the `Super` key, I have access to a [search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PacU7.png) where I can find applications.

I was previously (on Pop 20) able to search through directories for files using this search bar. Is there a way to re-enable this functionality?

Comment: This forum is about Ubuntu, not POP!-OS. This problem may, or may not, be specific to the OS you use, because it may depend on how Gnome Shell is configured.

Comment: I specifically said that Id reverted to the default GNOME shell which is on Ubuntu

Comment: Pop_OS is based on Ubuntu, but *is* not Ubuntu. Support for Ubuntu may be valid, but it also may not. This board is limited to official flavors of Ubuntu only.

Comment: In the future, a question like this should start off with something like:
> I'm using GNOME vNN which is included in Ubuntu vNN so I'm hoping someone here might be able to help. I've searched the PopOS community with no luck.
As your question is currently written (with no mention of Ubuntu) and with your low reputation number, it's understandable the people's first reaction is, "you're in the wrong place." However, we all owe it to each other to be welcoming and helpful. That includes being helpful in our questions as well as our answers.